# What's the best approach to generate image based on user submitted text on server side like Rails

Tags: image, imagemagick

Guys,

I see ImageMagick is capable to generate image using Pango formatted text, which looks like quite a good approach.

Just want to know if there's anything else out there, what's the most recommended way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imagemagick` is probably the easiest, but `ghostscript` can also be used to render images with text.

Here's a little postscript program that displays some text.

```
%!
5 5 moveto
/Palatino-Roman 20 selectfont
(Some Text) show
showpage
```

Using `ps2eps` will calculate the Bounding-Box and add this information as a comment conforming to the *Document Structuring Conventions*.

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0 EPSF-2.0
%%BoundingBox: 5 5 97 20
%%HiResBoundingBox: 5.500000 5.000000 97.000000 19.500000
%%EndComments
% EPSF created by ps2eps 1.64
%%BeginProlog
save
countdictstack
mark
newpath
/showpage {} def
/setpagedevice {pop} def
%%EndProlog
%%Page 1 1
5 5 moveto
/Palatino-Roman 20 selectfont
(Some Text) show
showpage
%%Trailer
cleartomark
countdictstack
exch sub { end } repeat
restore
%%EOF
```

Then imagemagick's `convert` utility can render this as an image.

[image: sample image of some text]

The `ps2eps` is necessary so the final image is cropped to the interesting part, rather than at the bottom of a page-sized image.

Here's a typescript of the whole sequence. `0>` is the command prompt.

```
0> cat > t.ps
%!
5 5 moveto
/Palatino-Roman 20 selectfont
(Some Text) show
showpage
0> ps2eps t.ps
Input files: t.ps
Processing: t.ps
Calculating Bounding Box...ready. %%BoundingBox: 5 5 97 20
Creating output file t.eps...** Warning **: Weird heading line -- %! -- ready.
0> convert t.eps t.png
```